# How can I align these three cards inside of the same div?

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to add three card divs that are horizontally aligned within a larger container.  I have them set to `display: inline-block` but the divs are jumbled and not on the same line.

I have tried using in-line and in-line block settings and neither are successful at aligning the three divs.

```css
.card {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 350px;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="lowmid">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">
      <img class="activator" src="./photos/oaxaca.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="card-content">
      <span class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">more_vert</i></span>
      <p><a href="#">This is a link</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-reveal">
      <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">close</i></span>
      <p style="color: black">Here is some more information about this product that is only revealed once clicked on.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">
      <img class="activator" src="./photos/india.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="card-content">
      <span class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">more_vert</i></span>
      <p><a href="#">This is a link</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-reveal">
      <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">close</i></span>
      <p style="color: black">Here is some more information about this product that is only revealed once clicked on.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">
      <img class="activator" src="./photos/za.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="card-content">
      <span class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">more_vert</i></span>
      <p><a href="#">This is a link</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-reveal">
      <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">close</i></span>
      <p style="color: black">Here is some more information about this product that is only revealed once clicked on.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The card divs are not aligned, instead they are jumbled across the page despite the fact that I have placed the card divs within a larger container, given them each a uniform size, and set each to `display: inline-block`.

Please help me align these three card divs so that they can be horizontally aligned on the same row, within the div with the id `#lowmid`

Comment: But they looked horizontally aligned in the output. https://prnt.sc/ovbrtu Did you add the custom CSS correctly?

Comment: As Manoj said, the output looked fine. In any case, you could always use flexbox as I have answered below.

Answer (score 1):

Add `display:flex` to the container.

```
#lowmid{
  display:flex;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can either use html table:

```
<table width="100">
  <tr>
    <td valign="bottom">card1</th>
    <td valign="bottom">card2</th>
    <td valign="bottom">card3</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

or css grid: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid_container.asp